# Verbal windows shutdown/startup

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, shutdown

The question is for both windows xp and server 2003. Especially the latter takes ages to shutdown and startup and doesn't give information on what it's actually doing. Is there a way to get it to be more verbally? Like Linux tells what it's actually doing when it's starting up or shutting down.

Thanks,

Ernst

I've been told exchange is busy during the shutdown, but I'd like to see what it's doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's no way I know of the deactivate the bootscreen of Windows and switch to status messages instead (except the safe mode, yes). But you could [let it create a boot log](http://www.windowsreference.com/general/how-to-create-a-bootlog-in-windows-2000xp-and-later/).

Comment: That should help a bit, but is there something for shutdown as well?